# Set Limit number of data to be inserted in roomDb

Tags: java, android, sql, roomdb

I am  inserting data in my roomDb table. I want only 10 row to be generated when storing the data in table. if 11th entry comes in table then in FIFO(first in First Out) manner the first entry should get deleted and new data should be added in table row on first index of table as it is latest entry in table.

This is my query for inserting data in table. i have added onConflict just to not make duplicate entries
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insert(RecentWatchedModel recentWatchedModel);